# PHP timeout doesn't stop the script?

Tags: php, time, timeout, max, execution

I was expecting some error like 500 or timeout page with the following code:

```
<?php
      ini_set('max_execution_time',5);
      set_time_limit(5);
      echo 'start';
      sleep(10);
      echo '<br/>hi';
```

However, I get something like this:

```
start
hi
```

Did I do something incorrect?

All I want is see the script stoped when timesout in the 5thd second, so the second echo should not be executed(I know this is quite a weird requirement)

Could anyone shred a light, thanks.

PS: seems the sleep() part is quite a distraction, how about I change the code like this:

```
<?php
      ini_set('max_execution_time',5);
      set_time_limit(5);
      echo 'start';
      for($i=1;$i<100000000;$i++){
          if($i%100==2) echo $i;
          else echo '--';
      }
      echo '<br/>hi';
```

Comment: I'm not going to make this an answer, because you're probably running the latest version of PHP. But if you're running an older version with safe_mode turned on (before that feature was removed) then set_time_limit and ini_set('max_execution_time') have no effect.

Comment: hi in my phpinfo, I can see max_execution_time but no set_time_limit

Comment: @zhaopeng do you have any `sleep` calls in your "work" code? How do you know that it's taking longer than the max_execution_time?

Comment: That's normal. Max_execution_time is a configuration directive that can be set in your php.ini file (that's how it _has_ to be set when safe mode is on) while set_time_limit() is a function called within a script that just affects the rest of that script.

Comment: @J, I don't have sleep in my work code.  you can actually change the sleep part, to a loop which runs, say 1000000000 times, to echo something,  which of course will be more than the max_execution_time I set(1 second)

Comment: @martin, I tried safemode on, still not working.

Answer (score 6):

According to this comment in php.net you must be using unix...
["Please note that, under Linux, sleeping time is ignored, but under Windows, it counts as execution time."](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php#75557) (Sleep is not taken into consideration as part of the execution time in Unix/Linux.)

Additionally, to make it timeout simply loop forever

```
<?php
while (true) {
    // i'll error out after max_execution_time
}
```

To see how long that is, you can either find out the execution time using [microtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) or inquire about the max_execution_time variable you just set.

```
$max_time = ini_get("max_execution_time");
echo $max_time
?>
```

**UPDATE**
With your updated code, the output is as expected.

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 5 seconds exceeded in newfile.php on line 7
```

Comment: Thanks J.  But in my example, sleep is merely something I try to make the script running long. It could be some other long-running code instead.    By the way, yes, it is running under Linux tho.

Comment: So this is the correct answer then. In linux, time spent sleep()ing is ignored.

Comment: To see how long that is, you can either [find out the execution time using microtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) or inquire about the max_execution_time variable you just set using `ini_get('max_execution_time');`

Comment: I never knew this! Not that I've ever needed to `sleep()` until execution timed out. A quick test on my server *seems* to confirm (I was dubious since the comment was posted in 2007). Anyone have any details about why?

Comment: @J, with your way "while(true)", I get a dead-loop and this time I use ini_set to make max_execution =  1.... so weird..